# Knowing the order in which the javascript files are loaded in the page

Tags: javascript, requirejs, google-chrome-devtools

I am using requirejs to load all the javascript files in my application. Now i want to know the order in which the files are loaded in the page. So is there a way to get to know that in chrome dev tools?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the chrome dev tools, you can open the network tab.